# why my recorded video become 0 bytes after uploaded to server using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, video-capture

my app tries to capture a video, and then the result will be sent to server

so I capture the video using the code below, but when I upload it to server, the file size is always 0 byte

because I create it in temporary file ?

[image]

here is the code to record a video

```
     private fun recordVideo() {


        val videoFile = createVideoFile()

        videoFile?.let {
            videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,"com.video.record.fileprovider",it)
            val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,videoUri) 
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        }

    }

    private fun createVideoFile() : File? {
        val fileName = "myVideoAndroid"
        val storageDir = mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
        return File.createTempFile(fileName,".mp4",storageDir) // <---- because I make it in temporary file ?
    }
```

and here is the provider tag in the manifest

```
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.video.record.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

        </provider>
```

and here is the file path xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="my_videos"
        path="Android/data/com.xxxx.mediauploader/files/Movies"/>

</paths>
```

the video seems good before uploading to server, I can play it perfectly.

and then I upload it using retrofit by using the code below

the interface

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("uploadvideo")
    fun uploadVideo(
            @Part video: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Call<UploadResponse>
```

and then used it like this

```
private fun createVideoFile() : File? {
    val fileName = "myVideoAndroid"
    val storageDir = mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    return File.createTempFile(fileName,".mp4",storageDir)
}

val file = File(createVideoFile()!!.absolutePath)
val fileVideoPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("videoFile", file.name, RequestBody.create("video/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file))
val call = uploadMediaAPI.uploadVideo(video = fileVideoPart)

call.enqueue(object : Callback<UploadResponse>  {


})
```

I can upload it successfully, but the result is always 0 bytes in server

how to solve this ?

Comment: You call createVideoFile(). Which creates an empty file (and deleted the old one)  and then you upload this empty file. That is the whole mistake. You should use instead the file you created before for the file provider. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I finally can solve this problem, maybe because the `videoUri` is created in temporary file, so we need to convert it to real file

pass this `videoFile` to your retrofit

```
val videoFile = fileFromContentUri(mContext,videoUri) // <--- pass your temporary videoUri here
```

the code for `fileFromContentUri` will be like this

```
    fun fileFromContentUri(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): File {
        // Preparing Temp file name
        val fileExtension = getFileExtension(context, contentUri)
        val fileName = "temp_file" + if (fileExtension != null) ".$fileExtension" else ""

        // Creating Temp file
        val tempFile = File(context.cacheDir, fileName)
        tempFile.createNewFile()

        try {
            val oStream = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
            val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)

            inputStream?.let {
                copy(inputStream, oStream)
            }

            oStream.flush()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return tempFile
    }

    private fun getFileExtension(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val fileType: String? = context.contentResolver.getType(uri)
        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(fileType)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun copy(source: InputStream, target: OutputStream) {
        val buf = ByteArray(8192)
        var length: Int
        while (source.read(buf).also { length = it } > 0) {
            target.write(buf, 0, length)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `finally can solve this problem, maybe because the videoUri is created in temporary file, so we need to convert it to real file` But that was not the cause. And that was not what you did.

Comment: You had an Uri which pointed to your file. And you used the uri to upload the file. But you used the uri as if it was a file path. But uries are not file paths. Well mostly not. So nothing was uploaded. After that you made a copy of the file and used the file path of the copy to upload the copy.

Comment: All this was not needed as you could use the uri directly to upload the file.

Comment: @blackapps I have tried so many ways actually but it didn't work. it will be more helpful if you have a better  code. yup maybe this is not a good way to solve the issue but it works

Comment: Of course its great you found a solution. But all was not needed. Not even using an uri. I now told you in a comment what went wrong.